# case not giving results back like if statement spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a def like this:

```
def formatMap(sep: String = ": ",
    left: String = "{", right: String = "}")(m: Map[String, String]) = {
  val items = m.toSeq.map{case (k, v) => {
   if( k contains "region") {
     s"$k$sep'$v'"
     } else {
     s"$k$sep$v"
     }
     }}.mkString(", ")
  s"$left$items$right"
}
```

but I need to convert it to a case to look at multiple rules and I tried to do this:

```
def formatMap(sep: String = ": ",
    left: String = "{", right: String = "}")(m: Map[String, String]) = {
  val items = m.toSeq.map{case (k, v) => {
   def val2($k: Any): Any = $k match {
      case "region" | "popn_typ_cd" | "prod_type_cd" | "ent_prod_cd" => s"$k$sep'$v'"
      case _ => s"$k$sep$v"
     }
     }}.mkString(", ")
  s"$left$items$right"
}
```

The second case just gives me back blank values...it doesn't seem to be outputting the `s"$k$sep'$v'"` or `"$k$sep$v"`

is my case statement setup correclty?

EDIT:

I got it to work like this:

```
def formatMap(sep: String = ": ",
    left: String = "{", right: String = "}")(m: Map[String, String]) = {
  val items = m.toSeq.map{case (k, v) => {
   if( k contains "region") {s"$k$sep'$v'"} else {
   if( k contains "popn_typ_cd") {s"$k$sep'$v'"} else {
   if( k contains "prod_type_cd") {s"$k$sep'$v'"} else {
   if( k contains "ent_prod_cd") {s"$k$sep'$v'"} else {s"$k$sep$v"}}}}
     }}.mkString(", ")
  s"$left$items$right"
}
```

but I would still like to know how to do it via the case statement...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the `def val2` in your version of `formatMap`:

```
def formatMap(sep: String = ": ",
    left: String = "{", right: String = "}")(m: Map[String, String]) = {
  val items = m.toSeq.map{case (k, v) => {
   def val2($k: Any): Any = $k match {
      case "region" | "popn_typ_cd" | "prod_type_cd" | "ent_prod_cd" => s"$k$sep'$v'"
      case _ => s"$k$sep$v"
     }
     }}.mkString(", ")
  s"$left$items$right"
}
```

you are creating a function, but you never call it.  Either you can
insert `val2(k)` before `}}.mkString(", ")` and use `$$k` instead of `$k` because your argument is called `$k` or even better you can just avoid
the `def` and write:

```
def formatMap(sep: String = ": ",
    left: String = "{", right: String = "}")(m: Map[String, String]) = {
  val items = m.toSeq.map { case (k, v) =>
   k match {
     case "region" | "popn_typ_cd" | "prod_type_cd" | "ent_prod_cd" => s"$k$sep'$v'"
     case _ => s"$k$sep$v"
   }}.mkString(", ")
  s"$left$items$right"
}
```

In action:

```
scala> formatMap()(Map("one" -> "eins", "two" -> "zwei", "region" -> "EU"))
res1: String = "{one: eins, two: zwei, region: 'EU'}"
```